# CCAvenue Payment Gateway Support for BHIM and UPI

Tags: payment-gateway, ccavenue, upi

We have decided to use CCAvenue Payment Gateway in our application. I have some doubts

1. Does CCAvenue Payment Gateway supports BHIM and UPI payments?
2. What are the difference between BHIM and UPI payments?
3. Does any standalone SDK for UPI?

Comment: 1: CCAvenue Payment Gateway supports UPI: [here you check](https://www.ccavenue.com/upi.jsp)
2: UPI is the platform while BHIM is a separate mobile wallet app, similar to Paytm, Mobikwik, Freecharge and others.
3: To integrate UPI SDK  you have to partner with a bank which is offering this service. Only UPI enabled banks are allowed to act as PSP (Payment service Provider).

Comment: is there any SDK for BHIM?How we can integrate BHIM payment in app?

Comment: Some UPI enabled banks are allowed to act PSP  like Yes Bank, RBL, ICICI Bank, Axis Bank.

You have to partner with that bank and they will provide you SDK. Once you get SDK, it is easy like plug n play.

You can also readout about upi from

https://digidhan.mygov.in/pages/pdf/sbi/NPCI%20Unified%20Payment%20Interface.pdf

Comment: Thanks Jestin. But I have to integrate BHIM app in my application. For eg : In Uber mobile application, the payment section shows Paytm, JioMoney etc.. Like this I want to show BHIM app in my payment methods

Comment: The first step to integrate BHIM UPI in your website/application is to partner or tie up with a BHIM as a merchant. Once you have the access to UPI SDK, you just need to add it to your developed  application to enable transactions using UPI.